# Angular JS Filtering in javascript controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

If I have something like :

```
{{(myList|filter:{state:"INFO"}).length}}
```

I am basically filtering on a specific Object property in my list. How do I do it in Javascript.

Currently the JavaScript takes only the value not the Object property.

```
$filter("filter")(myList,"INFO")
```

This works but isn't right as it looks for INFO in all object properties for single record.

```
$filter("filter")(myList,"INFO")
```

This is what I need but doesn't work as entire string is being used for filtering not treating as Object Property : **Value pair**

Any ideas around this ?

Comment: Have you tried `$filter("filter")(myList,{state:"INFO"})`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$filter('filter')(myList,function(item){
   return (item.state == 'INFO')
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfect for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

**An example of filtering Array of Objects based on key:value object property using Angular $filter in JavaScript | not in HTML template**

```
var data= $filter('filter')(myList, {state: 'INFO'});

// view data
if (console) console.log(data);
```